# Is "à quoi conduis-tu les enfants?" correct?

Tags: questions

I'm writing the question for `Je conduis les enfants à l'école`. Could you please elaborate on which one is correct?

- à quoi conduis-tu les enfants?
- Où conduis-tu les enfants?

Thank you so much for your explanation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est bien « où conduis-tu les enfants ? », car l'école est un lieu.

Comment: Note que même si on conduisait les enfants à leur entrainement de Judo ou de foot (plus communément exprimé par "au judo" ou "au foot", on dirait aussi "où". "A quoi conduis-tu les enfants", même si plus correct techniquement parlant, n'est pas idiomatique...

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, c'est tellement peu idiomatique que la tournure *à quoi conduis-tu* n'apparaît nulle part ailleurs que sur cette propre page : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A0+quoi+conduis-tu%22

Comment: In another context, the "à quoi" could be used : "A quoi ça nous conduit toute cette discussion ? A rien."

Comment: And if you didn't hear what the other person said : "Je conduis les enfants à l'[???] - Tu les conduis à quoi ? A l'école." But of course "Tu les conduis où ?" would work better.